# accessing context data in a class

Tags: python, django, view

I want to use DeleteView for different cases instead of rewriting a new function for every case. So I thought I pass the model as an argument in the URL and then select which delete to use by overriding the get_context_data function. My problem is how to access the context variable:

views.py:

```
class PDelete(DeleteView):

    template_name='kammem/delete.html'
    if context['model']=='Person':
        model=Person
        success_url=reverse_lazy('personer')
    elif context['model']=='Concert':
        model=Concert
        success_url=reverse_lazy('concert')

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
  
         context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['model']=self.kwargs['model']

         return context
```

urls.py

```
path('pdelete/<int:pk>/<str:model>',PDelete.as_view(),name='pdelete'),
```

The problem is that the context variable is undefined in the class. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the problem with having multiple views? Also instead of doing this you can simply write something like `DeleteView.as_view(model=Person, success_url=reverse_lazy('concert'))` in your urls for each of your models (you can perform some list comprehension if you want to reduce that also)

Comment: You would need to pass template_name also above `DeleteView.as_view(model=Person, success_url=reverse_lazy('concert'), template_name='kammem/delete.html')`

Comment: nice, can you access the model parameter in like this:  path('pdelete/<int:pk>/<str:model>',DeleteView.as_view(model=model,success_url=reverse_lazy('concert'), template_name='kammem/delete.html')) ?

Comment: **No**, why do you want to do things this way? any patterns that are caught are passed to the view. So you would need to override some method of the view. I believe something like `[path(..., DeleteView.as_view(model=model, ...), ...) for model in model_list]` should be what you want, but I disagree with doing things this way. You should simply **explicitly** write each url (why make things confusing for yourself and others reading the code?).

Comment: ok,  think I got it figured out, my basic thought was why duplicate a lot of code where the only diffrence is in the model name? but ok, I can create multiple path entries instead, like pdelete, cdelete etc, just giving a different model name.

Answer (score 0):

What you pass through url,is accessible via self.request.kwargs in your class methods.
You should implement the if conditions in one of your class methods,preferably delete method.
Also don't forget to delete the object when you are overriding delete method.